# Expectation of the stochastic process

Tags: expected-value

Consider the following stochastic process.

- $X(t)=Y(t-1)$ where $Y(t-1)\sim Normal(X(t-1)+1,\sigma^2)$
- $X(0)=1$

Now I am interested in the $E[X(n)]$. 
Intuitively, I think $E[X(n)]$ is equal to $n$. 
Is this the correct answer? If it is, how can I show this mathematically?

Comment: Is this a discrete time process? You might be able to use induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s simple induction. From $E[X(t)]=E[X(t-1)]+1 $ you can easily get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate little bit more?

Comment: $E[X(t)] = E[X(t-2)]+2=E[X(t-3)]+3=...=E[X(0)]+n